# when linux kernel is crashed how kernel stack and call trace logged to console?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
Pid: 16251, comm: bash Not tainted 2.6.32.59 #78

Call Trace:

 [<ffffffff81367a50>] ? do_page_fault+0x1b6/0x394

 [<ffffffff8136583f>] ? page_fault+0x1f/0x30

 [<ffffffff812160c5>] ? sysrq_handle_crash+0xd/0x16

 [<ffffffff812164be>] ? __handle_sysrq+0xaf/0x14a

 [<ffffffff8121659e>] ? write_sysrq_trigger+0x45/0x4c

 [<ffffffff81216559>] ? write_sysrq_trigger+0x0/0x4c

 [<ffffffff81116468>] ? proc_reg_write+0x85/0xa6

 [<ffffffff810d54cc>] ? vfs_write+0xa8/0x14c

 [<ffffffff810d566e>] ? sys_write+0x48/0x9e

 [<ffffffff8102d025>] ? sysenter_dispatch+0x7/0x2b

BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)

IP: [<ffffffff812160c5>] sysrq_handle_crash+0xd/0x16

PGD 26ad8f067 PUD 1e2aa6067 PMD 0 

Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
```

which component of linux logs these Info to console?

Comment: That would be [printk](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/printk?id=refs/tags/v4.8.11).

Comment: @sudheer Also see panic(): http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/panic.c?v=3.11#L30

Comment: panic() and dump_stack() both Functions ...call printk().

Comment: @sami   panic() and dump_stack() both Functions  call printk(). But does printk generate output  on console?? i think.. It sends o/p to a kernel ring buffer. how these messages are coming to console??

Answer (score 0):

These log will be printed in panic function of kernel.

A Linux kernel panic will be called when  the Linux kernel cannot quickly or easily recover, including bad drivers, overtaxed memory and software bugs.

When panic was called, it will use vsnprintf and dump_stack etc. API to show some useful info about the reason of the issue on console, if you enable KDUMP feature, you can also trigger load crash kernel, and you can do some custom action in this function to help to gather needed info when kernel crash:

```
  linux/kernel/panic.c

/**
 *      panic - halt the system
 *      @fmt: The text string to print
 *
 *      Display a message, then perform cleanups.
 *
 *      This function never returns.
 */
NORET_TYPE void panic(const char * fmt, ...)
{
....
    bust_spinlocks(1);
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
....
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE
    dump_stack();
#endif
   ....

    /*
     * If we have crashed and we have a crash kernel loaded let it handle
     * everything else.
     * Do we want to call this before we try to display a message?
     */
    crash_kexec(NULL);

    kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_PANIC);


    kcore_logon(1);
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Kernel panic - not syncing: %s\n",buf);
....
```

Comment: panic() and dump_stack() both Functions  call printk(). But does printk generate output  on console?? i think.. It sends o/p to a kernel ring buffer. how these messages are coming to console??